# Azure Synapse web activity calling "pipelineruns" rest api , fails with "failureType": "UserError"

Tags: azure-synapse

I have Azure Synapse pipeline with web activity. I would like to call "pipelineruns" rest api to get run details of a pipeline.
I am using the below settings for the web activity
URL:
https://workspacename.dev.azuresynapse.net/pipelineruns/d855ac65-4196-45b7-8b8f-3899e3cd14f6?api-version=2020-12-01
method:get
Authentication: System managed identity
resource: https://dev.azuresynapse.net

I get the below error
Troubleshoot activity failures
{
"errorCode": "2108",
"message": "{\n  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",\n  "title": "Not Found",\n  "status": 404,\n  "traceId": "00-b12c13a9e429cd4c998fc4a7c9c2d06e-85c4dbbbf7c29144-00"\n}",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Web1",
"details": []
}

The same pipeline works in another environment. Could somebody please help.

I tried in another environment and it works

Answer (score 0):

As per [MS_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/pipeline-run/query-pipeline-runs-by-workspace?tabs=HTTP) ,I reproduce same in environment. I tried with following filter its working fine.

**1.Based on last Update time**

```
{  
  "lastUpdatedAfter": "2022-06-16T00:00:00.0000000Z",  
  "lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-01-30T05:18:53.027417Z"  
}
```

**2.last Update time with Run status**

```
{  
  "lastUpdatedAfter": "2022-06-16T00:00:00.0000000Z",  
  "lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-01-30T05:18:53.027417Z",  
  "filters": [  
    {  
      "operand": "Status",  
      "operator": "Equals",  
      "values": [  
        "Pipeline 1"  
      ]  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

[image]

For more information **refer** this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/785376/get-pipeline-runs-by-workspace-api-not-functioning).